# Deploy Grails 2.3.0 to Glassfish Server

Tags: grails, deployment, glassfish

I have an application build with Grails 2.3.0 and type command 'grails war' to generate a war file.
I type following command to deploy the application :

```
asadmin deploy APP_PATH/target/myapp.war
```

But I get the following error:

```
remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [myapp] : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 137; columnNumber: 15; 

Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [myapp].  cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: 從元素 'init-param' found invalid content。expect '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":run-as, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":security-role-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":multipart-config}'。. Please see server.log for more details.
```

I use Grails 2.3.0 and get the same error on both Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and Glassfish 4.

How can I fix this error ?
Any help would be appreciate.

-- Update

I use grails command "grails install-templates" to generate web.xml, and move web.xml to web-app/WEB-INF, but still got the same error message. Following is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
         metadata-complete="true"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>/@grails.project.key@</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>@grails.project.key@</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>characterEncodingFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>

    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Grails dispatcher servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>grails</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>dispatchOptionsRequest</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <!-- The Groovy Server Pages servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>gsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>gsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.gsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <!-- 30 minutes -->
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <!--
        The order of the welcome pages is important.  JBoss deployment will
        break if index.gsp is first in the list.
        -->
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.gsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: There is a parsing error in your web.xml. Please add it to the question.

Comment: I have updated my question, and add my web.xml content. Thanks.